# RStudio Workbench No package called 'car' when loading ggpubr

Tags: r

I cannot manage to get the car package to download on RStudio Workbench version R 4.1.1. I am attempting to use the stat_cor function and get the error that it could not find function stat_cor, and from looking things up online, I need to download the ggpubr package and when I download it, I get the error:

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggpubr’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
> there is no package called ‘car’

So my next step is to download car but I get another error from there essentially saying "Configuration failed for package 'nloptr'" and also "dependency 'nloptr' is not available for package 'lme4'" and lastly "dependency 'lme4' is not available for package 'car'". I tried installing nloptr and get the same error.
I am new with this, but if I want to use the stat_cor function I need ggpubr, and for ggpubr I need car to work right? Any help would be great.

```r
install.packages("ggpubr")
install.packages("car")
library('ggplot2')
library('ggpubr')
library('car')
```

Comment: Please provide the exact output of these commands. When you try to install `nloptr` you can the same error that "nloptr" is not available? Or does it mention a different package name.

Comment: Yes trying to install nloptr gives a long output and eventually ends with "Error: Configuration failed for package 'nloptr'

Comment: Well, "configuration failed" is very different than "not available." Usually there are more details in the error message that point to the exact cause.

Comment: Please show us *all* of the results of `install.packages("nloptr")` (edit your question by cutting and pasting the full text into a code block) ...